# What's the expected behavior when TCP connection is lost?

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol

I looked through FIX v4.2 spec, it is not clear to me what the expected behavior it should be when the TCP connection is lost in the middle of a session.

More specifically, suppose the current sequence number is 100 and at this point the TCP connection is lost, when either side tries to resume the session, it re-sends message number 100, or starts a new session with logon?

In describing FIX session, the spec says one session has one logon and one logout, but could go across multiple physical connections. This leads me to think that when the TCP connection is lost, the resuming process should not be starting with a logon message, but I am not positive on that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FIX protocol does not define anything related to the transport protocol.  There were some documents on the official web site that only suggest how it can be implemented on top of this or that protocol, but only suggests.

Therefore, the expected behavior in case of TCP/IP disconnect depends on implementation. For instance, it is possible to have a system that does not care about TCP/IP disconnects at all, which would make those details irrelevant. In that case, the expected behavior would have been to continue sending receiving messages after connection is re-established, and of course proceed to a “recovery” of lost messages, if any. In reality, though, I have never seen a system like that.

In practice, all systems treat TCP/IP disconnects as implicit lose of session and expect clients to send a logon upon re-connect.

When logging in, there are two options — a re-connecting session may send the next outgoing sequence number or it may ask server to reset the sequence (to 1). In first case, the server side may send a logon acknowledgement if sequence is greater or equal to what it expected, or close (or even reject) the session if the received sequence number is less than expected. Additionally, if the sequence was greater than expected, server will issue a re-transmission. Client session monitors the sequence of the server as well, and needs to request a re-transmission if it detects a gap (received sequence is greater than expected). In the second case, if the server supports sequence reset, both in and out sequences are reset to 1 and no messages are recovered.

In your case, if connection is lost after sending a message with sequence number 100, client would have to re-connect and send a logon with sequence 101, and proceed from there. Alternatively, connect and reset the sequence, in which case some messages might get lost.

Also, don’t forget to check specifics of the venue you connect to. There could be very weird details that are not specified by the FIX protocol at all, or even those going against the FIX protocol. For instance, ICE (indeed one of the most brain-dead exchanges in general) is one of the silliest exchanges in this regard — it doesn’t allow re-connecting within first 15 seconds, and then if clients cannot connect for 30 seconds, they should switch to a failover server. If failover happens, they fail to keep the sequence number in tact, and clients are left no choice but reset the sequence number.

Hope it makes things a bit clearer for you. Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

If the transport layer is TCP/IP, I would expect the session initator to:

1. Re-establish a socket connection
2. Send a new logon message

The sequence number to use on the logon message depends on the type of session and what has been agreed with the FIX session acceptor (see the spec for details).  For sessions where there is no value in replaying any lot messages e.g. market data feeds where the prices would be stale, it makes sense to send a logon message with sequence number 1 and set tag 141=Y (to reset the sequence numbers).  For an orders session, where message replay might be required, the session initiator should generally logon with a sequence number of one greater than the last message sent (and expect a logon response from the FIX session acceptor with sequence number of 1 greater than the last message received).

Unless you really need the message replay, it is cleaner and easier to reset the sequence numbers each time upon logon.  This obviously depends on the FIX session acceptor (FIX server) support for this.  For things like STP feeds, I've found this to be far more reliable and it is generally better for the application protocol to provide application level replay facilities rather than relying on the brittleness of FIX session replay.